# Exporting the results of TukeyHSD test with basic descriptive statistics by factor group to excel

Tags: r

I would like to export the results of TukeyHSD test with basic descriptive statistics by grouping factor to excel file. I have a data frame with factor containing 16 levels:

```
main.data <- runif(256) 
main.factor <- c("1st control", "2nd control", "Control A", "Control B",
           "Variant A", "Variant B", "Variant C",
           "1st Variant", "2nd Variant", "3rd Variant",
           "Treatment 1", "Treatment 2", "Treatment 3",
           "1st Treatment", "2nd Treatment", "3rd Treatment")

df <- data.frame(experiment=rep(main.factor,each=16), Main.value=main.data)
df$experiment <- factor(df$experiment, levels = c("1st control", "2nd control", "Control A", "Control B",
                                                "Variant A", "Variant B", "Variant C",
                                                "1st Variant", "2nd Variant", "3rd Variant",
                                                "Treatment 1", "Treatment 2", "Treatment 3",
                                                "1st Treatment", "2nd Treatment", "3rd Treatment"))
```

I am using one-way ANOVA and after TukeyHSD test:

```
model.1 <- lm(Main.value~experiment, data=df)
anova(model.1)
library(agricolae)
result <- HSD.test(model.1, "experiment", group=F); result
```

I would like to export results of TukeyHSD test and basic descriptive statistics by grouping factor. I have tried this:

```
result.1 <- result$comparison
library("xlsx")
write.xlsx(result.1, file = "main.result.xlsx", col.names = TRUE, row.names = TRUE, sheetName = "TukeyHSD_test")
```

The main problem is that comparison is in alphabetical order, but I want to use this order:

```
factor.order <- c("1st control", "2nd control", "Control A", "Control B", "Variant A", "Variant B", "Variant C", "1st Variant", "2nd Variant", "3rd Variant", "Treatment 1", "Treatment 2", "Treatment 3", "1st Treatment", "2nd Treatment", "3rd Treatment")
```

It is possible to change? It can be also export result to excel with empty row? I would like to add empty row when the first factor level was compaired to other factor levels (first empty row), the second factor level was compaired to others (second empty row), third factor level was compaired to other (third empty row) etc.

When I export the result of descriptive statistics by grouping factor, it is also in alphabetical order. How can I change?

```
result.2 <- result$mean
write.xlsx(result.2, file = "main.result.xlsx", col.names = TRUE, row.names = TRUE,
       sheetName = "descriptive_statistics", append = TRUE)
```

Can somebody help me? Thank You very much.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(agricolae)
library(tidyverse)
library(xlsx)

main.data <- runif(256) 
main.factor <- c("1st control", "2nd control", "Control A", "Control B",
                 "Variant A", "Variant B", "Variant C",
                 "1st Variant", "2nd Variant", "3rd Variant",
                 "Treatment 1", "Treatment 2", "Treatment 3",
                 "1st Treatment", "2nd Treatment", "3rd Treatment")

df <- data.frame(experiment=rep(main.factor,each=16), Main.value=main.data)
df$experiment <- factor(df$experiment, levels = c("1st control", "2nd control", "Control A", "Control B",
                                                  "Variant A", "Variant B", "Variant C",
                                                  "1st Variant", "2nd Variant", "3rd Variant",
                                                  "Treatment 1", "Treatment 2", "Treatment 3",
                                                  "1st Treatment", "2nd Treatment", "3rd Treatment"))

factor.order <- c("1st control", "2nd control", "Control A", "Control B", "Variant A", "Variant B", "Variant C", "1st Variant", "2nd Variant", "3rd Variant", "Treatment 1", "Treatment 2", "Treatment 3", "1st Treatment", "2nd Treatment", "3rd Treatment")

model.1 <- lm(Main.value~experiment, data=df)
result <- HSD.test(model.1, "experiment", group=F)

result.1 <- result$comparison
result.2 <- result$mean

result_1_sheet = result.1 %>% 
  rownames_to_column("grouping_factor") %>% 
  separate(grouping_factor, into = c("factor_a", "factor_b"), sep = " - ") %>%
  mutate(
    factor_a = fct_drop(factor(factor_a, levels = factor.order)),
    factor_b = fct_drop(factor(factor_b, levels = factor.order))
  ) %>% 
  arrange(factor_a, factor_b) %>% 
  group_by(factor_a) %>% 
  group_modify(~ add_row(.x)) %>% 
  mutate(
    factor_a = as.character(factor_a),
    factor_a = ifelse(is.na(factor_b), NA, factor_a)
  ) %>% 
  as.data.frame()

result_2_sheet = result.2 %>% 
  rownames_to_column("group") %>% 
  mutate(group = fct_drop(factor(group, levels = factor.order))) %>% 
  arrange(group) %>% 
  as.data.frame()

write.xlsx(result_1_sheet, file = "main.result.xlsx", col.names = TRUE, sheetName = "TukeyHSD_test")
write.xlsx(result_2_sheet, file = "main.result.xlsx", col.names = TRUE, row.names = FALSE,
           sheetName = "descriptive_statistics", append = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank You very much, it is working perfectly, have you got any idea in case of "result.2"?

Comment: Hi @BaltazárTivadar, I have updated it to include result.2 as well.

Comment: Thank You again @tauft, but the modified version for the "result_1_sheet" does not work now. When I run this new code, the first column (factor_a) contains only numbers instead of name of factor levels. Besides, when I try export this result to excel I got the following error message: "Error in if (is.na(value)) { : the condition has length > 1" Please, could you check again?

Comment: Oh right - I have fixed it now to keep the factor labels and used openxlsx to save the file.

Comment: Thank You again @tauft, but unfortunately I still have problems. In case of "result_1_sheet" column "factor_b" does not have order "factor.order", therefore the multiple comparison is little different from this, what I would like. Other problem is that the comparison is in case of first factor level (1st control) is OK, there are total 15 comparison and after is empty row, but in case of second factor level (2nd control) there are only 12 comparison and empty row, but it must be total 14 comparison and empty row, in case of third factor (Control A) 13 comparison and empty row etc.

Comment: In this case empty rows must will be: 17, 32, 46, 59, 71, 82, 92, 101, 109, 116, 122, 127, 131 and 134. For me is important to export results with help of function "write.xlsx" from package "xlsx", but I always getting the following error message: "Error in if (is.na(value)) { : the condition has length > 1" What does it mean? @tauft Please, could you fix all of these problems?

Comment: I edited it to work with the xlsx package.

Comment: Thank You again, it works @tauft. Please, could you fix these problems which I wrote in the first comment? There are other problem with "result_1_sheet", beacause column "factor_b" does not have order "factor.order" and empty rows are in wrong place (see above for details).

Comment: Hi @BaltazárTivadar, factor b column is ordered by factor.order for me. The comparisons showing are what is in the data. If you look at `result.1` there are only 12 rows that start with 2nd control (the second factor level).

Comment: Thank You @tauft Your help, but this comparison is still wrong. For example: in case of group "2nd control": There must be total 14 comparison and empty row, because in case of "1st control" there are 15 comparison. In case of comparison "2nd control" these comparisons are missing: between "2nd control and 1st Variant" and between "2nd control and 1st treatment". Similar problems are in case of other factor levels. In case of "Control A" there are only 7 comparison instead of 13. Please could you fix it?

Comment: Hi @BaltazárTivadar, the question was about exporting the results - you can make a new question if you need help with getting the correct results from the test.

Comment: Thank You for Your help @tauft. The question was the exporting of the results getting by TukeyHSD with dependence of ordered grouping factor to excel. "Result_2 " is OK, in this case the factor level is OK, but in case of "Result_1" factor order in "column_2" is not OK.  I think it is not necessary make a new question.